# Ionic React loop firebase object in ion content

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I am new to typescript and firebase. How do I loop an firebase object because i cannot use it using map function. If possible, I want to convert it to an array in order for me to loop it. Here is what I tried:

```
const [doctors, setDoctor] = React.useState([]);


  useIonViewDidEnter(()=>{
    console.log('Enter')
    firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('type').equalTo('doctor').on('value',(snapshot)=>{
          // console.log(snapshot.val())
          setDoctor(snapshot.val())
          // event.detail.complete()
        })
  })
```

And my return html look like

```
        <IonList>
        {doctors.map(elem => {
            return(
              <IonItem key={elem['uid']} onClick={getDoctors}>
              <IonLabel>
                <IonText className="font-weight: bold;">
                <h3>{elem['name']}</h3>
                </IonText>
                <h4>{elem['speciality']}</h4>
                <h4>{elem['email']}</h4>
              </IonLabel>
              <br></br>
            </IonItem> 
            )
          })}
        </IonList>
```

Sample of my firebase data
[image]

Also i cannot use something like `v-for` like in vue js in order to render directly in the template. if someone know what should I do please feel free to comment. Thanks in advance!!